# Isn't Pulumi Azure API support too old / how fast are new API versions implemented?

Tags: azure, pulumi, pulumi-azure

I am thinking about using Pulumi for Azure and was curious how up to date the API support is. I checked the storage account as an example.

- Pulumi: [API Version 2021-02-01](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/storage/storageaccount/)
- latest version according to Microsoft docs: [API version 2022-09-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts?source=recommendations)

Isn't that an issue? How fast is Pulumi in adding features from new API versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulumi automatically generates new SDK versions that are always up to date with the Azure APIs. So even though the documentation you linked might not show the newest version, the SDK already supports it.

https://www.pulumi.com/blog/full-coverage-of-azure-resources-with-azure-native/

> Unlike the classic Azure provider, which requires manual work to keep updated, we designed the native provider to stay always up-to-date with Azure API additions and changes. We generate Pulumi SDKs for the native Azure provider automatically from Azure API specifications published by Microsoft. We publish daily builds of the provider and have published 210 versions of the provider in the last six months.

You can find the sources for the API version you mentioned on GitHub: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/tree/master/sdk/dotnet/Storage/V20220901